# Official IOS5 Twitter API Rate Limit Anyone?

Tags: api, twitter, ios5, limits, rate

I have developed an App that integrates Twitter both using `TWRequest` and `TWTweetComposeViewController`

At the peak of game play, it will post no more than 15 Tweets in an hour.  Unless the user explicitly sends more tweets.

Even with this low number, my IOS5 App is being Rate Limited by Twitter.

I know this is the case because I can see immediately when the tweets stop during game play.  I can switch Twitter Accounts when that happens and the tweets will work on the new account.

Furthermore, it appears that it takes about 8 to 12 hours for this Rate Limit to be lifted.  Once that happens, I can use my original account to play the game again.

**NOW TO MY QUESTION:**

15 Tweets per hour seems very low to get limited.  I can't find the official Rate Limit for IOS5 Apps on Twitters website.  Does anybody know it or where the documentation can be found?

The closest I have come is the [Twitter Developer Rate Limits](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting) page, which says 150 per hour!